# dynamically set <img> "title" attribute to be same as "alt"

Tags: javascript

This is my following code:

```
<div class="w3-container" id="menuAuthor" style="float:left">
   <a href="/Author/Benjamin-Franklin-Quotes/213"  class="textnone  fl"  ><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Benjamin-Franklin.jpg" alt="Benjamin Franklin Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Winston-Churchill-Quotes/356"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Winston-Churchill.jpg" alt="Benjamin Franklin "/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Thomas-Jefferson-Quotes/253" class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Benjamin-Franklin.jpg" alt="Thomas Jefferson"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/George-Washington-Quotes/54" " class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/George-Washington.jpg" alt="George Washington"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Martin-Luther-King-Jr-Quotes/53"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Martin-Luther-King-Jr.jpg" alt="Martin Luther King, Jr. Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Helen-Keller-Quotes/62"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Helen-Keller.jpg" alt="Hellen Keller Quotes"/></a>
   <a href="/Author/Henry-Ford-Quotes/63"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Henry-Ford.jpg" alt="Henry Ford Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Ronald-Reagen-Quotes/64"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Ronald-Reagen.jpg" alt="Ronald Reagen Quotes" /> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Theodore-Roosevelt-Quotes/69"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Theodore-Roosevelt.jpg" alt="Theodore Roosevelt Quotes" /> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Pope-John-Paul-2-quotes/65"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Pope-John-Paul-II.jpg" alt="Pope John Paul 2 Quotes" />   </a>
   <a href="/Author/Abraham-Lincoln-Quotes/55"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Abraham-Lincoln.jpg" alt="Abraham Lincoln Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Vince-Lombardi-Quotes/56" class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Vince-Lombardi.jpg" alt="Vince Lombardi Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Albert-Einstein-Quotes/60"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Albert-Einstein.jpg" alt="Albert Einstein Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Mahatma-Gandhi-Quotes/50"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Mahatma-Gandhi.jpg" alt="Mahatma Gandhi Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Nelson-Mandela-Quotes/59"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Nelson-Mandela.jpg" alt="Nelson Mandela Quotes"/> </a>

</div>
```

I have set the alt attribute inside the `img` tag for each element.

I want to set the `title` attribute, considering both the `title` &`alt` attributes will have the same value.

Is there any javascript that can be run to set the title attribute?

Comment: isnt a relevant question?

Comment: You didn't provide your attempt. "Please give me the codes" questions don't really sit well here.

Comment: @Liam It makes perfect sense: OP wants some JavaScript to do `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).forEach(function(img) {img.setAttribute("title",img.getAttribute("alt"));});` and.. I just answered the question in a comment again, didn't I?

Comment: Considering there will be other image tags in the html file. I want to do just for img tag only inside the id="menuauthor"

Comment: I we reading a different question? Ok, this question makes no sense to me. I've read it several times now and I have no idea what he's saying. I can see what your answer (in the comments mean). I can't relate this to the question though...

Comment: @Venkat `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#menuauthor img'))....` - come on, this is basic stuff. If that's too difficult, just put the `title` attribute in the HTML like the rest of us.

Comment: The title you gave this question was unrelated to the actual question. please ask in the title exactly what you want to achieve next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setAttribute` & `getAttribute`

```js
var getChilds = document.querySelectorAll("a.textnone img");
getChilds.forEach(function(item) {
  item.setAttribute('title', item.getAttribute('alt'));
})
```

```html
<div class="w3-container" id="menuAuthor" style="float:left">
  <a href="/Author/Benjamin-Franklin-Quotes/213" class="textnone  fl"><img class="w3-circle" style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Benjamin-Franklin.jpg" alt="Benjamin Franklin Quotes" /> </a>
  <a href="/Author/Winston-Churchill-Quotes/356" class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle" style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Winston-Churchill.jpg" alt="Benjamin Franklin " /> </a>
  <a href="/Author/Thomas-Jefferson-Quotes/253" class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle" style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Benjamin-Franklin.jpg" alt="Thomas Jefferson" /> </a>
  <a href="/Author/George-Washington-Quotes/54" " class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/George-Washington.jpg " alt="George Washington "/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Martin-Luther-King-Jr-Quotes/53 "  class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Martin-Luther-King-Jr.jpg " alt="Martin Luther King, Jr. Quotes "/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Helen-Keller-Quotes/62 "  class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Helen-Keller.jpg " alt="Hellen Keller Quotes "/></a>
   <a href="/Author/Henry-Ford-Quotes/63 "  class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Henry-Ford.jpg " alt="Henry Ford Quotes "/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Ronald-Reagen-Quotes/64 "  class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Ronald-Reagen.jpg " alt="Ronald Reagen Quotes " /> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Theodore-Roosevelt-Quotes/69 "  class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Theodore-Roosevelt.jpg " alt="Theodore Roosevelt Quotes " /> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Pope-John-Paul-2-quotes/65 "  class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Pope-John-Paul-II.jpg " alt="Pope John Paul 2 Quotes " />   </a>
   <a href="/Author/Abraham-Lincoln-Quotes/55 "  class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Abraham-Lincoln.jpg " alt="Abraham Lincoln Quotes "/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Vince-Lombardi-Quotes/56 " class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Vince-Lombardi.jpg " alt="Vince Lombardi Quotes "/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Albert-Einstein-Quotes/60 "  class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Albert-Einstein.jpg " alt="Albert Einstein Quotes "/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Mahatma-Gandhi-Quotes/50 "  class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Mahatma-Gandhi.jpg " alt="Mahatma Gandhi Quotes "/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Nelson-Mandela-Quotes/59 "  class="textnone fl "><img class="w3-circle "  style="width:40px " src="/images/authors.small/Nelson-Mandela.jpg " alt="Nelson Mandela Quotes "/> </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetch all the elements with tag name and since, tag name returns `HTMLCollections`, Array.from is converting the collection to an array.
We can iterate over the array using `forEach()` and set the property.

```js
var images = document.getElementById('menuAuthor').getElementsByTagName('img');

Array.from(images).forEach(function(ele){
  ele['title'] = ele['alt'];
});
```

```html
<div class="w3-container" id="menuAuthor" style="float:left">
   <a href="/Author/Benjamin-Franklin-Quotes/213"  class="textnone  fl"  ><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Benjamin-Franklin.jpg" alt="Benjamin Franklin Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Winston-Churchill-Quotes/356"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Winston-Churchill.jpg" alt="Benjamin Franklin "/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Thomas-Jefferson-Quotes/253" class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Benjamin-Franklin.jpg" alt="Thomas Jefferson"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/George-Washington-Quotes/54" " class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/George-Washington.jpg" alt="George Washington"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Martin-Luther-King-Jr-Quotes/53"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Martin-Luther-King-Jr.jpg" alt="Martin Luther King, Jr. Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Helen-Keller-Quotes/62"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Helen-Keller.jpg" alt="Hellen Keller Quotes"/></a>
   <a href="/Author/Henry-Ford-Quotes/63"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Henry-Ford.jpg" alt="Henry Ford Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Ronald-Reagen-Quotes/64"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Ronald-Reagen.jpg" alt="Ronald Reagen Quotes" /> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Theodore-Roosevelt-Quotes/69"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Theodore-Roosevelt.jpg" alt="Theodore Roosevelt Quotes" /> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Pope-John-Paul-2-quotes/65"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Pope-John-Paul-II.jpg" alt="Pope John Paul 2 Quotes" />   </a>
   <a href="/Author/Abraham-Lincoln-Quotes/55"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Abraham-Lincoln.jpg" alt="Abraham Lincoln Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Vince-Lombardi-Quotes/56" class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Vince-Lombardi.jpg" alt="Vince Lombardi Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Albert-Einstein-Quotes/60"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Albert-Einstein.jpg" alt="Albert Einstein Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Mahatma-Gandhi-Quotes/50"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Mahatma-Gandhi.jpg" alt="Mahatma Gandhi Quotes"/> </a>
   <a href="/Author/Nelson-Mandela-Quotes/59"  class="textnone fl"><img class="w3-circle"  style="width:40px" src="/images/authors.small/Nelson-Mandela.jpg" alt="Nelson Mandela Quotes"/> </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Way to copy my solution from the comments. 10/10 would plagiarise again.

Comment: Well, I didn't copy, I came this on my own.

Comment: I am fetching all the elements with tag name and since, tag name returns HTMLCollections, `Array.from` is converting to an array, then I am iterating through each image element and setting the `title` from `alt` property.

Comment: @HassanImam No no, I mean [edit] your answer and explain it to the OP (I don't expect you to prove me that it's not your code, i'm just asking you to make your answer better by explaining it, then I could upvote it)

Comment: Edited it, if you feel anything is missing, you can further edit it.

Comment: @HassanImam Thank you. Now your answer include all the necessaries